# RestKit: How to resubmit failed request after re-authenticating?

Tags: ios, restkit

The API I'm developing against requires me to present an authentication token in a custom HTTP header. This token expires every few minutes, and could happen while the user is still within the app as long as they have been idle long enough. When the token has expired I receive a 403 response but I only find out after attempting a request.

What's the best way to get RestKit to automatically reauthenticate and retry the request so I don't have to put in this logic everywhere I make a request? Responses to similar questions have suggested using the RKRequestDelegate protocol or the RKObjectLoaderDelegate protocol but unfortunately these are no longer part of RestKit (as of 0.20).

Any idea what the "correct" approach should be now? Should I be subclassing RKObjectManager and tacking on a retry to each of the request operations or should I provide a custom HTTPOperation or HTTPClient class or is there some better approach altogether? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch it in Failure block , and check for the status code and re-do the authentication

```
    RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOp = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[getObjResp]];

            [requestOp setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                ....
                }
            } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
// Here your status code check                
// Here your retry-code
                }
```

Comment: How would one do the retrying part without knowing the details of the request ?