# RestKit - RKRequestDelegate does not exist

Tags: ios, restkit

I've installed RestKit into Xcode and it builds fine. However, I seem to be missing at lot of classes. I am trying to add The RKRequestDelegate class as a delegate to one of my view controllers but this delegate does not exist. I'm also missing RKRequest class.
I've looked in the RestKit folder on my hard drive and I cant see them there. 
Perhaps I've missed a step along the way. If anyone else has come across this it would be great to hear a solution.

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't do anything wrong – it seems RestKit no longer contains RKRequestDelegate as of 0.20.0

You can compare the API docs for [0.10.3](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/) and [0.20.0-pre6](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0-pre6/) to verify this.

Depending on what you wanted to use RKRequestDelegate for, you could use one of the new delegates or perhaps you could also subclass RKObjectManager (search the [RKObjectManager docs](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKObjectManager.html) for "Customization & Subclassing Notes" for examples of when that might be appropriate).

That said, I must caveat that I too am uncertain how what the "right" approach is for the problem I'm facing ([how to retry a request after re-authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154755/restkit-how-to-resubmit-failed-request-after-re-authenticating)) and haven't been able to find anything definitive for that in the docs. Hopefully your use case is more clear cut.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a pity that most if the examples online for restkit now seen to be outdated since this update

Answer (score 3):

Here's a wiki about upgrading from 0.10.x to 0.20.0:

> https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0

As you see, really a big change.. And for `RKRequestDelegate`, as it said:

> The delegate protocols RKRequestDelegate and RKObjectLoaderDelegate have been removed from the project in favor of block based approaches. The most common, required methods of these protocols such as request:didLoadResponse:, request:didLoadError:, objectLoader:didLoadObjects:, and objectLoader:didLoadError: have been replaced with completion blocks on the AFHTTPRequestOperation and RKObjectRequestOperation classes. In general, these completion blocks are specified as a pair of success and failure blocks

seems tricky..