# RestKit - Repeat request if auth timeout

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm talking to a .NET Web API 2 service, using it's default "Individual User Accounts" authentication. I'm using RestKit 0.22.0.

My issue is that when a session timeout occurs, I want to have the iOS app re-authenticate with the stored credentials and then replay the request. The only way I've found to do this is [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154755/restkit-how-to-resubmit-failed-request-after-re-authenticating) - asked a year ago. However I do not think that the answer should be to check if the status code is 401, re-authenticate, retry the request *in every failure block*. As that's just a lot of copy and pasting!

Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a common method from the failure block which takes the required inputs. Preferably you might want to have multiple common methods which are capable of verifying the response details and restarting the process automatically (so 1 for GET, 1 for POST, ...).

---

Pseudo code

```
- (void)do something with this info: 
{
    ... calculate method specifics then call general method ...
    [self getObjectsAtPath:urlArg parameters:p success:s];
}

- (void)getObjectsAtPath:urlArg
              parameters:p
                 success:s
{
    [RK getObjectsAtPath:urlArg
              parameters:nil
                 success:
     { -- Yay -- call success callback
       s();
     }
                 failure:
     { -- Humph -- retry
       ... do auth updates, then retry ...
       [self getObjectsAtPath:urlArg parameters:p success:s];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  

How would I make a common method for it to repeat the request if the method signatures of all my requests are different? Eg. I have `-(void)requestAllObjects;` and `-(void)requestObjectWithID:(int)id;`. (The actual method signatures include success and failure blocks also)

Comment: You may have many methods but RestKit only has a few. So you can have your methods call another set of your methods with an interface like the RestKit methods. These methods handle the retry logic (if success, call callback, else call recursive to retry).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean have something like this? `-(void)checkFailureBlock:(RKObjectRequestOperation *)operation actionToRepeat:(void(^)())actionToRepeat failure:(void(^)(NSString *errors))failure
{
    if (operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode == kHTTP_STATUS_CODE_UNAUTHORIZED)
    {
        [[AccountService sharedInstance] login:^{
            actionToRepeat();
        } failure:failure];
    }
}
` So I make a call to this in the failure of all methods - The block `actionToRepeat` is a call to the same method again if the `login` is a success.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. I accept that this is the way to do it - I just feel like it's cumbersome! I thought there might be a way to work into the RKRequestOperation that if it fails because of HTTP Status unauthorised then do X, then repeat the initial request. This would save all my failure blocks from knowing anything about auth - and they could handle another sort of failure.

Comment: If you can make the solution generic then you can update RestKit and submit a pull request to have it included into the repo.

Comment: Haha! If I was able to do that I would. I was hoping someone might have done something like that already. I'm not terribly familiar with RestKit. Thanks again.